# group data from json

Tags: php, json, api

i want show table product base of supplier, data from json
final display like this

supplier 1
product 1
product 2
product 3

supplier 2
product 1
product 2
prodoct 3

here is my json data

```json
{
   "data":{
      "query":[
         {
            "key":"a27239eaec62ba6405f5e9f0fb715bd5"
         }
      ],
      "status":[
         {
            "code":202,
            "description":"ok"
         }
      ],
      "results":[
         {
            "id":"177",
            "user_id":"87",
            "supplier_id":"6",
            "product_id":"36",
            "product_name":"Tripod octopus",
            "varian_id":"141",
            "varian_name":"Varian Acak",
            "jumlah":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"178",
            "user_id":"87",
            "supplier_id":"8",
            "product_id":"37",
            "product_name":"Pembersih Mata Buah Nanas",
            "varian_id":"140",
            "varian_name":"Acak",
            "jumlah":"3"
         },
         {
            "id":"179",
            "user_id":"87",
            "supplier_id":"8",
            "product_id":"42",
            "product_name":"Gunting dahan pohon",
            "varian_id":"135",
            "varian_name":"gunting dahan",
            "jumlah":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and here is my code without grouping data

```
$datainventory = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$totalRecord = count($datainventory['inventory']['results']);
for ($j=0; $j < $totalRecord; $j++) 
{
 echo  $datainventory['data']['results'][$j]['supplier_id'];
 echo  $datainventory['data']['results'][$j]['product_name'];
}
```

please any one can grouping my data json? thank you

Comment: What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was got the answer

```
 foreach ($newdatainventory as $supplier_id => $product) 
    {
    foreach ($product as $productname) 
      {

       }
 
    }
```